# Combine UPDATE with UNION

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, union

I am currently doing this in a loop (pseudo as below):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $totRisk; $i++) {
    $query = "UPDATE myTable
                SET 
                    _RiskName='val', 
                    _Control='ctrl'
                WHERE 
                    id = '$i'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn_report, $query);
}
```

Not efficient I know. So I want to union all the update queries in one sql statement,
but it shows error.

Here is the SQL query that I tried:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET 
_RiskName='vala', 
_Control='ctrla'
WHERE 
id = '1'
UNION
UPDATE myTable 
SET 
_RiskName='valb', 
_Control='ctrlb'
WHERE 
id = '2'
```

but it says there is error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around:
> 'UNION UPDATE myTable SET _RiskName = 'val', _Control = 'ctrl' WHERE
> id =' at line 8

Is it possible to union UPDATE queries? If not, then how can I loop thru my values and update all the rows in that table more efficiently?

Comment: ```... WHERE id IN ('1','2')```.

Comment: 'Is it possible to union UPDATE queries? ' - no it isn't possible

Comment: Does that really work? Combining multiple UPDATE via UNION

Comment: @Akina sorry didn't mention clearly both data are different for each id. I edit the my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using it in a loop. It works so why not.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $totRisk; $i++) {
    $val1 = valAArr[$i];
    $val2 = valBArr[$i];
    $query = "UPDATE myTable
                SET 
                    _RiskName='$val1', 
                    _Control='$val2'
                WHERE 
                    id = '$i'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn_report, $query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE myTable 
JOIN ( SELECT '1' id, 'vala' _RiskName, 'ctrla' _Control
       UNION ALL
       SELECT '2', 'valb', 'ctrlb' ) new_data USING (id)
SET myTable._RiskName = new_data._RiskName, 
    myTable._Control = new_data._Control;
```